# Pandas groupby two column and set unique id

Tags: pandas

does anyone know how to group by two column in pandas i.e. col1 and ol2 shown in the screenshot and set a unique ID start from 1 if within the same col1 there are different col2? if the col1 is different, then the unique ID should start from 1 again.

[image]

I couldnt find a way. my current solution does not meet my expectation as the unique id doesnt start from 1 if col1 is different.

```
df["NewID"] = df.groupby(['Col1','Col12'] ).ngroup().add(1).astype(str)
```

which gives me the following value
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `pd.factorize` and `groupby`:

```
new_id = lambda x: pd.factorize(x)[0]+1
df['New ID'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(new_id)
print(df)

# Output
    col1 col2  New ID
0      1    A       1
1      1    A       1
2      1    A       1
3      1    B       2
4      1    B       2
5      1    C       3
6      2    E       1
7      2    F       2
8      2    A       3
9      3    B       1
10     3    B       1
11     3    B       1
12     3    B       1
13     3    C       2
14     3    C       2
```

Or:

```
new_id = lambda x: x.ne(x.shift()).cumsum()
df['New ID'] = df.groupby('col1')['col2'].transform(new_id)
```

Comment: Heyy thanks for the answer :), I wonder what if I have more than 1 column example df["newId]=df.groupby('col1')[['col2', 'col3','col4']].transform(new_id), is there a way to do that? :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also `groupby` within each group

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'col1':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],
    'col2':['A','A','C','A','B','D','Q','R','S'],
})

#groupby twice to restart the group numbering
df['new_id'] = df.groupby('col1').apply(lambda g: g.groupby('col2').ngroup()).add(1).values
```

Output:

[image]